# Notepad++ NppFTP [SFTP] Connection failed : kex error

Tags: connection, notepad++, sftp

When I connect Virtual Ubuntu system on my Windows, find a question like this:

```
[SFTP] Connection failed : kex error : did not find one of algos diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 in list curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 for kex algos
```

I want to know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

> mcedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

add this two lines at the end of file:

> KexAlgorithms
>   diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
>   Ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr

now restart sshd

> service sshd restart